# Python OpenPyXl to move rows to master workbook

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm working on a script that will take the rows [2:lastRow] of the first sheet of a workbook and copy those rows to a master workbook, at the end of the current rows on that master workbook.

Here is the current code:

```
import time
import openpyxl
import os

print('Running "Excel Compiler" program...')
print('Please type first report number to add to file:')

firstFileNumber = input()
print()
print('Thanks! Working...')
firstFileName = str('report'+firstFileNumber+'.xlsx')
fileNumber = firstFileNumber
fileName = firstFileName
fileToCopy = openpyxl.load_workbook(firstFileName)
#replace line below with proper file name in CWD
masterFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('masterFile.xlsx')


while True:
    sheet = fileToCopy.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    lastRow = int(sheet.max_row)
    rows = sheet[2:lastRow]

    #now with rows needed assigned to variable "rows", move to master
    masterSheet = masterFile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    masterLastRow = int(masterSheet.max_row)
    for cellObj in rows:
        masterSheet.append(cellObj.value)


    #finalizing and saving
    wb.save(masterFile)

    #changing fileToCopy
    fileNumber = int(fileNumber + 1)
    fileName = str('report'+fileNumber+'.xlsx')
    fileToCopy = openpyxl.load_workbook(fileName)
```

So, basically, this script is attempting to assign the second through the last row of some "report" excel file to the variable "rows", and then append that variable, "rows" to the end of the master document.

I'm not sure if the append action is the proper one to use here. The rows must simply add to the next blank row on the master workbook, to avoid overwriting previously added rows.

When running my current code, I get the error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Programs/excelCompiler.py", line 46, in 
    masterSheet.append(cellObj.value)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

I want to know how to grab all cell values from rows 2 through the last row, and then what operation will paste the entirety of those rows to the master document, at the end of the main page of the master document. To make matters simply, formatting does not matter at all. I simply need cell values.

Comment: Also, I've only been coding for a few days now, so I'd appreciate feedback on structure / how to ask questions, etc. if anyone has advice. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `rows` is a list of rows, not a list of cells.